# array of hex values like range('a','z')

Tags: php

PHP has the function `range()` which can be used to loop through letters `a-z`. Is there something similar or a similar function that can let me loop through hex values `0-9` + `a-f`?

Comment: I think you should make clear what values you need. If string representation is fine for you, use my answer. If you need actual value (0..15), then use @futureal's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
array_merge( range(0,9), range('a','f') )
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean ASCII value equivalents, you can do:

```
$merged_result=array_merge(range('0','9'),range('a','f'));
```

Answer (score 2):

The numbers don't actually change, just how you are outputting them. So something like:

```
for (range(0,15) as $value) {
  $value = base_convert($value,10,16);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to do that loop from 0-15. `dechex($yournumber)`.

0x0 = 0

0xF = 15

```
for($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++) {
    print dechex($i);   
}
```